# Css Sub Menu Can't click in IE

Tags: css, submenu

I have made a menu that shows a sub menu after mouse hover. On Firefox and Chrome it works, but when I test in IE, it does not work. The problem is that mouse hover shows the main menu and the sub menu, but when I try to click the sub menu it is gone. Can you check the menu code, please?

```
#main_menu ul li ul {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 top: 20px;
 padding: 0;
 z-index: 599;
}
#main_menu ul li ul li { margin-right: 0px; }
#main_menu ul li:hover ul { 
 background-color:#fff;
 display:block; 
 height:30px;
}
```

Comment: could you go back an mark some answers as right on your profile?... http://stackoverflow.com/users/1192406/moreinet What IE version are you talking about?

Comment: I have to fix somebody code, is make me confuse, If I have made by myself is no problem.

Comment: and I don't want to make all change, if you can help I will very thank. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

IE only registers hover events for anchors. I think.

Comment: This is true for older versions of IE.

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen since he did not mention what IE Version he is talking about...

Answer (score 1):

delete the last UL before the `{`:

```
#main_menu ul li:hover {
```

instead of

```
#main_menu ul li:hover 
 ul{
```